# Change SVG fill color with <use> tag not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I just want to change the svg fill color and hover color. But I saw this svg attached like this:

```
<use xlink:href="#search-magnify"></use>
```

I think it's referring to this svg somewhere from the website. I just want to change the fill color without editing the original svg. So I tried wrapping it on span with class and style this way.

```
.icon svg path{
  fill: red;
  color: red;
}
```

But it's not working at all. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bfctx9u/).

What am I missing here? Can this not be achieved by css?

Comment: Then it will change it's original svg file fill color also.

Comment: Try this CSS .icon svg * {
  fill: red;
}
.icon svg:hover * {
  fill: black;
}

Comment: See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uLe0c87b/

Comment: Not working at all.

Comment: What effect do you want? May be I got it wrong. Can you please tell again

Comment: I need to set fill color as red without editing original svg.

Comment: My CSS is changing the fill color for the small icon at bottom of html.. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Use this class maybe it will help: svg#search-magnify path.st4 {
    fill: red;
}

 svg#search-magnify path.st4:hover {
    fill: black;
}

Comment: Looks like you have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367069/why-is-style-not-applied-to-svg-element-in-firefox/48368084#48368084)

Comment: @NanditaSharma Your example is working fine. When I applied it to my real website, it's not working at all. https://ibb.co/MS4v6Jt Very strange

Comment: @RobertLongson But it's working Nanditha example

Comment: @janath on Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

When using the `<use>` command, SVG elements fall into the `shadow DOM`

Read the article:
[Styling SVG  Content with CSS](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) by Sara Soueidan

> The Shadow DOM is similar to the normal DOM except that, instead of
>   being part of the main document subtree, nodes in the Shadow DOM
>   belong to a document fragment which is basically just another subtree
>   of nodes which are not as vulnerable to scripts and styles as normal
>   DOM nodes are. This gives authors a way to encapsulate and scope
>   styles and scripts when creating modular components. If you’ve ever
>   used the HTML5 video element or the range input type and wondered
>   where the video controls or range slider components came from, then
>   you’ve already come across the Shadow DOM before.

Therefore, add color inheritance for `path`

```
.icon svg path {
    fill: inherit;
}
use.sm {
    fill: red;
}
```

Below is the full code

```css
.icon svg path {
    fill: inherit;
}
use.sm {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="search-magnify" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 57 57" style="enable-background:new 0 0 57 57;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="st4" d="M55.1,51.9L41.6,37.8C45.1,33.6,47,28.4,47,23C47,10.3,36.7,0,24,0S1,10.3,1,23s10.3,23,23,23 c4.8,0,9.3-1.4,13.2-4.2L50.8,56c0.6,0.6,1.3,0.9,2.2,0.9c0.8,0,1.5-0.3,2.1-0.8C56.3,55,56.3,53.1,55.1,51.9z M24,6 c9.4,0,17,7.6,17,17s-7.6,17-17,17S7,32.4,7,23S14.6,6,24,6z">
</path>
</svg>
        
<span class="icon">
 <svg class="icon-svg svg-search" width="15%" height="15%">
 <use class="sm" xlink:href="#search-magnify"></use>
 </svg>
</span>
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/roj5a2yL/1/)

Comment: The strange thing is, If I put this into my real website, it's not working.

Comment: @Janath No, not like you. Look at me - `.icon svg path { fill: inherit }` And please check if you forgot to assign the class `<use class="sm"`

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. In css you are styling the use element not the path.
2. Here `<use xlink:href="#search-magnify"></use>` search-magnify should be the id of the path not the id of the svg element
3. You need also a viewBox for the svg element that is using the path

```css
.icon svg use{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon">
 <svg class="icon-svg svg-search" viewBox="0 0 57 57" width="20" height="20">
 <use xlink:href="#search-magnify"></use>
 </svg>
</span> 


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 57 57" style="enable-background:new 0 0 57 57;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="search-magnify" class="st4" d="M55.1,51.9L41.6,37.8C45.1,33.6,47,28.4,47,23C47,10.3,36.7,0,24,0S1,10.3,1,23s10.3,23,23,23 c4.8,0,9.3-1.4,13.2-4.2L50.8,56c0.6,0.6,1.3,0.9,2.2,0.9c0.8,0,1.5-0.3,2.1-0.8C56.3,55,56.3,53.1,55.1,51.9z M24,6 c9.4,0,17,7.6,17,17s-7.6,17-17,17S7,32.4,7,23S14.6,6,24,6z">
</path>
</svg>
```